# Continuing loop through ResourceNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, activeresource

I'm looping through a set of users and as part of that, I'm doing a call to a third-party API (via the [Intercom API Ruby wrapper](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ruby)).

The Intercom API throws an `Intercom::ResourceNotFound` if it can't find a user, and that stops the entire process.

I just want it to skip the user if it can't find it.

```
User.each do |user|
    user = Intercom::User.find_by_email(user.email) # Intercom::ResourceNotFound thrown if not found
    user.custom_data["Example"] = true
    user.save
end
```

Is this an issue with the Intercom Ruby wrapper? Or is there a typical Ruby or Rails way to handle this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just catching the Exception?

```
User.each do |user|
  begin
   user = Intercom::User.find_by_email(user.email) # Intercom::ResourceNotFound thrown if not found
   user.custom_data["Example"] = true
   user.save
  rescue Intercom::ResourceNotFound
  end
end
```

Since you just want to *skip* the user if he is not found (and an exception is thrown) there is no error-handling code after the `rescue`. But if you would want to put some debug message or something like that, you could just write:

```
  rescue Intercom::Resource
    puts %{Could not work on user...}
  end
```